# Facebook Chat API/ XMPP : Check if message has been delivered

Tags: facebook, limit, spam, smack, facebook-chat

Is there any way to get some info if a message has been delivered after sending it to the Facebook XMPP/Chat API Port?

I am using smack with scala and some messages i send get lost.

So far i found two XMPP extensions([XEP-0184](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html),[XEP-0079](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0079.html) ) which could give some feedback but does somebody know if the facebook XMPP server uses these or give any other type of response if message has been received?

Comment: Unfortunately, the XMPP protocol used to communicate with the Chat API is pretty constrained. You can ask your question again in the XMPP Developer Relations group on Facebook directly, maybe.